# Nivo charts tooltip is hidden behind other charts

Tags: reactjs, charts, nivo-react

[image: Please refer to this image]

When putting multiple charts tooltips from charts are hidden behind others.
Also, I am using custom tooltips for this picture, the default tooltip also shows in the same way.

Comment: please share code what you have done

Comment: order matters in the components layers prop, it will stack things in the order of the array passed to that prop.

Answer (score 0):

First, looks like you're using Canvas, maybe using the SVG version of your chart can help.

If it does not, you'll find more parameters for theming in this issue : https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues/308

Then you will be able to set precisely zIndex